# Default Parameters not allowed for non-string type variables in a web method

Tags: c#, asmx, webmethod

I have a web method in a web Service with default string parameters as follows

```
 public string Method1(string _userID, string _version, string _userAction, string deaultvar1="", string defaultvar2 = "")
    {//Method Logic}
```

Now I wrote another method in another webservice with int as default parameter as follows

```
 public string Method2(string _userIDSID, int defaultint1=-1)
        {//method2 Logic}
```

Now the `method2` thorws some exception if I don't pass any parameters for it.
but why do method1 works good and method 2 errors out as below.

```
System.ArgumentException: Cannot convert  to System.Int32.
Parameter name: type ---> System.FormatException: Input string was not in a correct format.
   at System.Number.StringToNumber(String str, NumberStyles options, NumberBuffer& number, NumberFormatInfo info, Boolean parseDecimal)
   at System.Number.ParseInt32(String s, NumberStyles style, NumberFormatInfo info)
   at System.String.System.IConvertible.ToInt32(IFormatProvider provider)
   at System.Convert.ChangeType(Object value, Type conversionType, IFormatProvider provider)
   at System.Web.Services.Protocols.ScalarFormatter.FromString(String value, Type type)
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at System.Web.Services.Protocols.ScalarFormatter.FromString(String value, Type type)
   at System.Web.Services.Protocols.ValueCollectionParameterReader.Read(NameValueCollection collection)
   at System.Web.Services.Protocols.HtmlFormParameterReader.Read(HttpRequest request)
   at System.Web.Services.Protocols.HttpServerProtocol.ReadParameters()
   at System.Web.Services.Protocols.WebServiceHandler.CoreProcessRequest()
```

Are default parameters only allowed for string types in web methods?

Comment: What is that actual error that you are receiving from method 2?

Comment: Edited the post with the error.

Comment: So, the code that is calling that function is passing a string value as opposed to an integer value.  Could you possibly be passing the method a  null value or something else that the program isn't expecting?

Comment: Are you testing it with the default testing page? If so, it takes each empty parameter as an empty string, overwriting the default value, and there you have that error (see that blank space after "convert" in "Cannot convert [    ] to System.Int32). Try testing it by code with a web reference and see if it works that way.

Comment: Yes, I am testing it with default testing page that VS gives me.let me see if it works by a web reference

Comment: it works using the Webreference.Good that rualmar comment helped me.

Comment: @Programmerzz Nice! I've been through that a couple of times. Maybe you should edit the question so next person reading this knows what we're talking about.